# Validating input for phone number string in BusinessSkinForms controls

Tags: c++builder, borland-c++

I am trying to get phone number as input from user in textbox (I am using Business Skin Forms `TbsSkinEdit`). Textbox should allow only numbers, spaces, dash and round brackets.  Is there any business skin form control which can solve this problem? Or is there any other way to achieve this?
Numbers can be in below format, format verification is not requirement, only allow specified characters in input -

(223)2312-1323

23324-3423-2342

23123123

2234 2343

I tried by overriding KeyPress event, but with that I am able to allow only numeric characters in textbox, but other operations like Paste and Ctrl+V needs additional handling. So checking if there is any ready control available.

Comment: As long as focus is in the text box, let the user enter whatever they do enter. Then, when they are leaving the text box, do your verification, and return focus to the text box, after a prompt for correction, if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use the `TbsSkinMaskEdit` component and set its `EditMask` property. It has some sample masks to choose from and one of the sample masks is for phone numbers:

`!\(999\)000-0000;1;_`

... but you may edit the mask yourself and set it to this for example:

`!\(999\)0000-0000;1;_`

---

If that doesn't cut it, you could create an `OnChange` event handler:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::bsSkinEdit1Change(TObject *Sender)
{
    TbsSkinEdit& se = *static_cast<TbsSkinEdit*>(Sender);
    decltype(se.Text) result;
    bool update = false;
    auto old_pos = se.SelStart - 1;

    for(auto ch : se.Text) {
        // numbers, spaces, dash and round brackets
        if((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == ' ' || ch == '-' || ch == '(' || ch == ')') {
            result += ch;
        } else {
            update = true;
        }
    }
    if(update) {
        se.Text = result;
        se.SelStart = old_pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: But that allows only fixed length string. What if my string length varies. See the sample numbers given.

Comment: @NileshShinde You can have optional characters, but when looking at the `TEditMask` documentation (which I haven't done in 15 years) I see that it looks hard to combine all your requirements.

Comment: @NileshShinde I added an alternative.

Comment: Paste function is not handled here. Posted another question for same - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63611320/tedit-ignore-paste-operation-if-clipboard-contains-specific-string

Comment: Paste operation should preserve old text as is, if pasted text contains alphabets. Should ignore complete text from clipboard and not accept partial text with numbers.

Comment: @NileshShinde  You only said "_other operations like Paste and Ctrl+V needs additional handling_" in this question. You mentioned nothing about that it has to preserve the text as is if the paste is rejected like you do in the new question.

Comment: In question I said I manage to handle key events, but Ctrl+V and Paste operation requires additional handling, so was looking for solution. You solution works if clipboard contains text 1234, abc124, abc but in case of 123abc it only pastes 123. In this case what I am expecting is it should ignore complete text. Along with keep text in clipboard as is.

Comment: @NileshShinde I know how the code I wrote works. It works as-if a user typed it in. It rejects only the invalid characters no matter how they got entered. I still think that this answer answers the question and that your new question is a different question all together.

Comment: Main requirement was related to handling Ctrl+V and Paste here, which is partially solved.

Comment: @NileshShinde Ok, I'll take a look at the other question :-)