# TEdit - ignore paste operation if clipboard contains specific string

Tags: borland-c++, rad-studio

I want to check clipboard string before paste happens into the TEdit control (using both Ctrl+V and context menu 'Paste'). If clipboard contains a specific string in it, then TEdit control should not paste that string. Clipboard text should remain as is, should not get cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `CTRL-V` you could create an `OnKeyPress` event handler to validate the text in the clipboard before it's pasted.

I made a combination of checking one single character against a table of valid characters and also checking the complete paste against invalid strings.

Note: The invalid strings may still be typed in manually since this is checking for invalid strings in the pasted text only. If you need to check so that a user doesn't type in bad strings one character at a time, call `valid_string()` in the `OnChange` event handler.

```cpp
#include <Clipbrd.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

// A function to validate a pasted string against a number of blacklisted strings
bool valid_string(const UnicodeString& InStr) {
    static const std::vector<UnicodeString> BadStrings{"  ", "--"};

    return std::find_if(BadStrings.begin(), BadStrings.end(), [&](const auto& badstr) {
        // return true if the current badstr was found
        return 
            std::search(InStr.begin(),
                        InStr.end(),
                        badstr.begin(),
                        badstr.end()) != InStr.end();
    }) == BadStrings.end(); // true if a bad string was NOT found
}
```

```cpp
// OnKeyPress event handler
void __fastcall TForm1::Edit1KeyPress(TObject *Sender, System::WideChar &Key)
{
    TEdit& se = *static_cast<TEdit*>(Sender);
    using StrType = decltype(se.Text);

    // A lambda to validate a single character:
    static const auto validkey = [](auto Ch) {
        // example of valid characters:
        static const StrType Accepted = "0123456789 -()";
        return std::find(Accepted.begin(), Accepted.end(), Ch) != Accepted.end();
    };

    if(Key >= ' ') {             // don't validate control characters
        // Single key validation
        if(not validkey(Key)) Key = 0;

    } else if(Key == 22) {       // CTRL-V - check that the whole clipboard buffer is ok
        auto& c = *Clipboard();
        if(c.HasFormat(CF_UNICODETEXT)) {

            // Extract the pasted string
            StrType paste = StrType(c.AsText.c_str());

            // Use the lambda on all characters
            bool all_chars_ok = std::all_of(paste.begin(), paste.end(), validkey);

            if(not (all_chars_ok && valid_string(paste))) { // reject the whole paste
                Key = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of doing it all in the `OnChange` handler instead. This should catch bad pastes from the context menu as well as if the user types in any illegal combinations (even if it consists of valid characters).

```cpp
#include <utility>

void __fastcall TForm1::Edit1Change(TObject *Sender)
{
    TEdit& se = *static_cast<TEdit*>(Sender);
    using StrType = decltype(se.Text);

    static StrType old_text;

    // A lambda to validate a single character:
    static const auto validkey = [](auto Ch) {
        // example of valid characters:
        static const StrType Accepted = "0123456789 -()";
        return std::find(Accepted.begin(), Accepted.end(), Ch) != Accepted.end();
    };

    // Making an unnecessary copy of the text.
    // Using se.Text's iterators directly fails for some reason.
    auto txt = se.Text;

    // Use the lambda on all characters
    bool all_chars_ok = std::all_of(txt.begin(), txt.end(), validkey);

    if(all_chars_ok && valid_string(txt)) {
        // All is ok, save this text
        old_text = std::move(txt);

    } else {
        // Revert back to the old text
        se.Text     = old_text;
        se.SelStart = old_text.Length();
        // se.Undo(); // May be a better idea to use instead.
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check for `CF_UNICODETEXT` instead of, or at least in addition to, `CF_TEXT`. In C++Builder 2009+, `TEdit::Text` and `TClipboard::AsText` will be `UnicodeString`, and `TClipboard::AsText` will use `CF_UNICODETEXT` internally.